# Print out files inside a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to initiate communication between a VPS and a rails application? I have done couple of research but I was not able to find a better solution to this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i didnt got idea how to start.

Comment: Is your rails app running on the VPS or are you trying to communicate remotely?

Comment: im trying to communicate remotely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways of listing files on a remote server depending on how you are able to access it. For example, if you have ftp access:

```
require 'net/ftp'

Net::FTP.open('example.com', 'username', 'password') do |ftp|
  files = ftp.list

  puts "list out files in root directory:"
  puts files
end
```

Alternatively, using SSH:

```
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('example.com', 'username', password: 'password') do |ssh|
  puts ssh.exec!('ls')
end
```

Comment: thank you this worked. Do you mind elaborating the other methods or can you share any resource on it?

Comment: Alternatives include ssh or if you can put code onto the server you could write an API which serves up the list of files and you'd then interact with that. I'll add an SSH example to my answer.